# Print from an object to a Sheet with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I'm totally new to VBA and i never coded anything similar. Anyway i'm not having any troubles with the logic and the code itself so i'm gonna post just a piece of my code to explain my question.
I have this two For that get my data from an API and then cleans them.
So if i execute this i can have the variable jsonRow as Object and i can extract the singles values from it.

```
Dim objRequest As Object
Dim strUrl As String
Dim blnAsync As Boolean
Dim strResponse As String
Dim page As String
Dim per_page As String
Dim Rows() As String

page=3
For i = 1 To page
    Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    strUrl = "https://***"
    
    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
        .SetRequestHeader "oauth-token", "***"
        .SetRequestHeader "hostname", "***"
        .SetRequestHeader "x-client-domain", "***"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .Send
        
        While objRequest.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        strResponse = .ResponseText
    End With
    
    Rows = Split(strResponse, "},", per_page + 1)
    GetArrayLength = UBound(Rows) - LBound(Rows)
    
    For x = 0 To GetArrayLength - 1
        Rows(0) = Replace(Rows(0), "{""data"":[", "")
        Rows(per_page - 1) = Split(Rows(per_page - 1), "}]", 2)(0)
        Rows(x) = Rows(x) & "}"
        'Rows(x) = Replace(Rows(x), "\", "")
        
        
        Set jsonRow = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Rows(x))

        Debug.Print Rows(x)
        Debug.Print jsonRow("numero_commessa")
        

    Next
    
Next
```

So as output i'll get something like:

Rows(x)

```
{"numero_commessa":"A00008","stato":"Aperta","tiratura":0,"isbn":"***","gredit":"80A","title":"VETTESE E AL*ART VISION A","dtcreate":"20\/07\/2021","type":"RISTAMPA","dtcons":"20\/07\/2021"}
```

and
jsonRow("numero_commessa")

```
A00008
```

What i need to do, now is "print" those data on a sheet (or even better in a table on a sheet) but i can't understand how. I can only founds examples that takes data from some sheet cells and copy that on other cell's.
So for every X i got an object and i need to put the values of this object on a different sheet row, on different columns of course.
Something like that:

[image]

I solved by using "Range" in the For x=0 loop.

```
Dim objRequest As Object
Dim strUrl As String
Dim blnAsync As Boolean
Dim strResponse As String
Dim page As String
Dim per_page As String
Dim Rows() As String

page=3
For i = 1 To page
Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
strUrl = "https://***"

With objRequest
    .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
    .SetRequestHeader "oauth-token", "***"
    .SetRequestHeader "hostname", "***"
    .SetRequestHeader "x-client-domain", "***"
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .Send

    While objRequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    strResponse = .ResponseText
End With

Rows = Split(strResponse, "},", per_page + 1)
GetArrayLength = UBound(Rows) - LBound(Rows)

For x = 0 To GetArrayLength - 1
    Rows(0) = Replace(Rows(0), "{""data"":[", "")
    Rows(per_page - 1) = Split(Rows(per_page - 1), "}]", 2)(0)
    Rows(x) = Rows(x) & "}"
    'Rows(x) = Replace(Rows(x), "\", "")


    Set jsonRow = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Rows(x))
        
        Range(Cells(Counter, 1), Cells(Counter, 1)).Value = jsonRow("numero_commessa")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 2), Cells(Counter, 2)).Value = jsonRow("stato")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 3), Cells(Counter, 3)).Value = jsonRow("tiratura")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 4), Cells(Counter, 4)).NumberFormat = "0"
        Range(Cells(Counter, 4), Cells(Counter, 4)).Value = jsonRow("isbn")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 5), Cells(Counter, 5)).Value = jsonRow("gredit")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 6), Cells(Counter, 6)).Value = jsonRow("title")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 7), Cells(Counter, 7)).Value = jsonRow("dtcreate")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 8), Cells(Counter, 8)).Value = jsonRow("type")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 9), Cells(Counter, 9)).Value = jsonRow("dtcons")
            
        Counter = Counter + 1


    Next

Next
```

i don't really like my code, specially my solution, but this is my first time with VBA, so if you have any other ideas or tips please correct it.

Comment: Have you tried two nexted For-Next cycle unsing Split function to extract the data from the string?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. 
Anyway, as you can see, i can have my data, in the example i print "numero_commessa". Now i need to show those data on an excell sheet

Answer (score 1):

Change the format of specific range,

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

I almost solved using "Range" in this way inside the For x=0:

```
For x = 0 To GetArrayLength - 1
        Rows(0) = Replace(Rows(0), "{""data"":[", "")
        Rows(per_page - 1) = Split(Rows(per_page - 1), "}]", 2)(0)
        Rows(x) = Rows(x) & "}"
        'Rows(x) = Replace(Rows(x), "\", "")
        'Debug.Print Rows(x)
        
        Set jsonRow = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Rows(x))
        
        Range(Cells(Counter, 1), Cells(Counter, 1)).Value = jsonRow("numero_commessa")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 2), Cells(Counter, 2)).Value = jsonRow("stato")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 3), Cells(Counter, 3)).Value = jsonRow("tiratura")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 4), Cells(Counter, 4)).Value = jsonRow("isbn")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 5), Cells(Counter, 5)).Value = jsonRow("gredit")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 6), Cells(Counter, 6)).Value = jsonRow("title")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 7), Cells(Counter, 7)).Value = jsonRow("dtcreate")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 8), Cells(Counter, 8)).Value = jsonRow("type")
        Range(Cells(Counter, 9), Cells(Counter, 9)).Value = jsonRow("dtcons")
            
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next
```

Now the only problem that i have is the isbn is a a string made with 13 numbers but excel show it in a weird way.
So "9788826817651" become 9,78883E+12 on the sheet.
can anyone helps me with that?

Also, i don't really like my code and specially my solution. Any tips?

This is a sample of my sheet:

[image]

Comment: Assuming the code can "know" the position of the headers, you might reduce those 9 lines to a single loop that cover all the headers to feed the `jsonRow`. Then again you might also store those variables in an array or in a properly formatted string. Or you could also use a split to directly extract the data from the `Row(*)` variable using `":"` and `","` as delimeters, but i guess that `jsonRow` already deal with some "translations" (like those dates you have). Is there anything else you don't like of your code?